# Disconnect layer.selectionChanged when project is being closed or layer removed

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5

On `QgsProject.readProject` I add a slot to some layer's `selectionChanged`. I tried disconnecting these slots in `QgsProject.layersWillBeRemoved` but here the project seems already closed, so I can't retrieve the layers to disconnect the slots.

There is a secont signature `layersWillBeRemoved(self, layers: Iterable[QgsMapLayer])` but I failed to connect to it.

```
@pyqtSlot(list)
def layersWillBeRemovedHandler(self, layers):
  #disconnect

... 

project.layersWillBeRemoved.connect(self.layersWillBeRemovedList) #without [list]
```

throws `decorated slot has no signature compatible with layersWillBeRemoved(QStringList)`.

`project.layersWillBeRemoved[list].connect(self.layersWillBeRemovedHandler)`

throws `there is no matching overloaded signal` whether the handler is decorated or not with `@pygtSlot(list)`.

So how do I solve this? Do I need to disconnect them at all, when the project is closed (or the layer is removed from the project)?

Comment: Is there any reason why you'd like to disconnect it yourself? When a `QObject` object (like `QgsProject` or `QgsMapLayer`) is destroyed, signals to and from the object are disconnected for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264750/qt-signals-and-slots-object-disconnect#9264888 and [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject)

Comment: Oh, great. I read a tutorial somewhere (can't find it anymore), that said, `always disconnect you should!`. So that was obviously wrong.

Comment: Then I'll post the comment as an answer, I think it's worth marking it as accepted so that other users searching for this topic can solve their doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason why you'd like to disconnect it yourself?

When a `QObject` object (like `QgsProject` or `QgsMapLayer`) is destroyed, signals to and from the object are disconnected for you. See [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject) and this thread in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264750/qt-signals-and-slots-object-disconnect#9264888).

Therefore, as soon as the layer is removed or the project is closed, the layer object will be deleted, therefore its SIGNAL-SLOT connections (including `selectionChanged`) will be automatically disconnected.